# Interior Angle Embedded in a Triangle Embedded in a Circle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

[image]

With only knowing the angles of $B$, $C$, and $D$ (shown above), is it possible to find the interior angle $A$? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The interior angle is always double the inscribed angle (in your case $D$).

Comment: So A would be 140°?

Comment: @JamieSanborn - yes.